# Dynamic joins using dbt macros

Tags: google-bigquery, dbt

I have an advertising events table and a sponsorships table. I want to join sponsorships to advertising events but join the data on certain criteria depending on the ad type or product type. Here is some example code:

```
with ad_events as (
select event_id, event_timestamp, event_type, ad_type, product_type, provider_id, topic_id, locational_bundle_id
from advertising_events
),

sponsorships as (
select sponsorship_id, sponsorship_type, provider_id, topic_id, location_bundle_id
from sponsorships
)

select events.*, coalesce(s1.sponsorship_id, s2.sponsorship_id, s3.sponsorship_id) as sponsorship_id
from ad_events events
left join sponsorships s1
on events.provider_id = s1.provider_id and 
    events.topic_id  = s1.topic_id and
    events.location_bundle_id = s1.location_bundle_id and
    events.ad_type in ('sponsored_doctor')
    events.product_type  = s1.sponsorship_type
left join sponsorships s2
    on events.topic_id = s2.topic_id and
    events.ad_type in ('anchor_video')
    events.product_type  = s2.sponsorship_type
left join sponsorships s3
on events.provider_id = s3.provider_id and 
events.topic_id = s3.topic_id and
    events.ad_type in ('hero_video')
    events.product_type  = s3.sponsorship_type
```

Is there a more clean way to do the join that maybe uses a csv that lists the ad_type, product_type, join_type, and fields_required_for_join so that we would only need to update the csv and have the joins be templatized in some way? Can you think of the simplest way possible that would be the most efficient to update and maintain when there are new ad types and join conditions? An example of the csv would be the following

ad_type,product_type,join_type,fields_required_for_join
hero_video,Hero Video,3,provider_id|topic_id
anchor_video,Anchor Video,2,topic_id
sponsored_doctor,Sponsored Doctor,1,provider_id|topic_id|location_bundle_id

What I have so far

-- macros/dynamic_sponsorship_join.sql

```
{% macro dynamic_sponsorship_join(ad_events_source, sponsorships_source, join_config_source, ad_events_cte, sponsorships_cte, join_config_cte) %}
with
{{ ad_events_cte }} as (
    select * from {{ ad_events_source }}
),
{{ sponsorships_cte }} as (
    select * from {{ sponsorships_source }}
),
{{ join_config_cte }} as (
    select * from {{ join_config_source }}
)
select
    events.*,
    coalesce(
        {% for join_condition in ref(join_config_cte) %}
            case
                {% for field in join_condition.fields_required_for_join.split('|') %}
                    when events.{% if loop.index == 1 %}{{ field }}{% else %} and events.{{ field }}{% endif %} is null then null
                {% endfor %}
                else s{{ loop.index }}.sponsorship_id
            {% endfor %}
        else null
    end
) as sponsorship_id
from {{ ad_events_cte }} events
{% for join_condition in ref(join_config_cte) %}
    left join {{ sponsorships_cte }} s{{ loop.index }}
    on
        {% for field in join_condition.fields_required_for_join.split('|') %}
            {% if field == 'gam_sponsorship_id' %}
                substring(s{{ loop.index }}.sponsorship_id, 0, 15) = events.gam_sponsorship_id
            {% else %}
                events.{{ field }} = s{{ loop.index }}.{{ field }}
            {% endif %}
            {% if not loop.last %} and {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
            and events.ad_type in ('{{ join_condition.ad_type }}')
            and events.product_type = s{{ loop.index }}.sponsorship_type
{% endfor %}
{% endmacro %}
```

I'm getting the following error: The object ("{obj}") was used as a dictionary. This capability has been removed from objects of this type.

Comment: can you provide sample data and expected results?